# Python: Tab gets stuck using Selenium and BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the source code for a couple of links using selenium and BeautifulSoup. I open the first tab to get the source code which works fine, but the second tab gets stuck. I think it's something with BeautifulSoup. Does anyone know why or of an alternative for BeautifulSoup? Here is the code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = []
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('about:blank')
for link in links:          
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
    browser.get(link)       
    source = str(BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source))            
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
driver.close()
```

Comment: What is the function of BeautifulSoup in your example? `browser.page_source` is already a string... well that's assuming `browser` is a typo for `driver` in both cases. Is this your exact code or did you retype it?

Comment: you need to change the active window that selenium activates upon.
`driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])` will switch to the last tab while `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])` will swich to the second one, etc. Also `browser.close()` will close the current window, Ctrl+w seems hackish.